# Opening java programs directly from an html page

Tags: java, html, button

I have created an html based page that contains buttons. On-click I want the buttons to open up java programs or games designed using swing but purely java. How can I do this? I will be doing this on one pc so access to the files that contain the java code will be available. This is my current html code and how I am trying to open up the java programs:

```
<script>
    function openGame(game) {
      // Replace the URLs below with the actual file paths or URLs of your Java programs
      switch (game) {
        case 'game1':
          window.open("D:\Coding 2023\TicTacToe");
          break;
        case 'game2':
          window.open('path/to/game2.java');
          break;
        case 'game3':
          window.open('path/to/game3.java', '_blank');
          break;
        case 'game4':
          window.open('path/to/game4.java', '_blank');
          break;
        default:
          console.error('Invalid game selected.');
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I want the buttons to open java programs

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about a Java Applet.

However, Applets have fallen out of favour as a method for delivering Java applications and I would strongly recommend you consider another approach. You will hit a lot of hurdles with poor browser support, multiple dialogues warning you of security issues and your users will need to install Java (and make sure they add browser extensions). We have been going through a process of converting all our applets to modern React/Angular applications and I'm glad to see the back of it.

So... I guess you are trying to use web pages to deliver Java applications to users' computers because you (a) want to write in Java and (b) appreciate that the web is the defacto way to give the world access to your apps...?

If so, I would accept that applets are dead and get your users to download your app, either as a runnable JAR, or a zip containing the JARs, maybe the JRE, maybe some shell scripts to run it, etc.

For a Swing launcher, try this:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    private JButton[] buttons;

    public MainFrame() {
        setTitle("Game Launcher");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400, 300);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        initializeButtons();
        createLayout();

        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void initializeButtons() {
        buttons = new JButton[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            buttons[i] = new JButton("Start game " + (i + 1));
            final int gameNumber = i + 1;
            buttons[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    launchGame(gameNumber);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void createLayout() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));

        for (JButton button : buttons) {
            add(button);
        }
    }

    private void launchGame(int gameNumber) {
        // Read configuration from file and pass it to the Game class
        String configFilePath = "game" + gameNumber + ".config";
        // Instantiate the Game class with the configuration
        Game game = new Game(configFilePath);
        // Start the game
        game.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MainFrame();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually because I am just documenting the process of doing this project for a school project. All I really need is for me to be able to make this happen on my device which already has the files of the java projects stored. With that in mind, is there any way I can open these java projects form some sort of designable interface (I thought the easiest interface would be a html page with buttons).

Comment: I'd open a simple swing interface with a button for each app. See my amended answer with a Swing code example.